# Highest lower bound on an NP complete problem

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np-complete, lower-bounds

What is the highest time complexity lower bound that has been proven on any (non-contrived) NP complete problem?

Comment: Closely related: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/17578/5038, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/17789/5038, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/21400/5038

Comment: Time complexity of what machine model? Single tape Turing machine? Multiple tape Turing machine? Word RAM?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Good question. Word RAM would be preferred.

Comment: What is non-contrived? I guess the one that is used for definition of $NP$ does not count. But the question can't be answered with 100% conviction as one would need to be able to read *every* paper on topic, which is impossible.